# $\lim_{s\to1}\frac{t-s}{1-s}$ when $0\leq s\leq t\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, indeterminate-forms

I was working on a topology exercise and got to a point (no pun intended) where I had to analyze the behaviour of $f(t,s)=\frac{t-s}{1-s}$ as s goes to $1$, under the assumption that $t\geq s$. It seems pretty obvious that the limit should exist and be equal to $1$, but I haven't been able to prove this. I'm still thinking about it, but in the meantime I figured I would ask here for advice on how to approach this. Of course I haven't ruled out the possibility that the solution is right in front of me, but I don't see it at the moment.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that $0\leq t,s\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=s+\lambda(1-s)$ with $0\le \lambda\le 1$ then

$$\frac{t-s}{1-s}=\frac{\lambda(1-s)}{1-s}=\lambda$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: That explains why I wasn't able to prove it, despite the stronger hypothesis that $0\leq s\leq t\leq 1$.

Comment: @ModestoRosado We can also take the extreme cases $t=s$ and $t=1$ which correspond to the $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=1$. I've given a version in a general form.  Bye

Comment: I don't know how I managed to miss those cases. Shame on me.

Comment: Good answer. Just to be clear, is it because there's literally no way for us to further uncover anything about $\lambda$, that when the limit equals $\lambda$ it's said not to exist?

Comment: @harry When limit exists it is assumed to be unique (uniqueness theorem). Here it depends on how we take $t$ with respect to $s$ therefore we say that “limit doesn’t exist”.

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist unless $t-s$ tends to $0$. If $t$ does not depend on $s$ then $t$ must be equal to $1$ for the limit to exist.

If $t$ does depend on $s$ then anything can happen. Try for example $t=2s$ and $t=s$.

Comment: @spinosaurus123 I forgot to mention that $0\leq t,s\leq 1$, which implies that $t-s$ tends to $0$ as $s$ goes to $1$.